# Import error with ctypes in python27, segmentation fault

Tags: python, ctypes

I am running python 2.7 on MacOSX, and started to get a segmentation fault when running anything related to ctypes. E.g.

```
>>> import ctypes
Segmentation fault
```

The error message being: "Python quit unexpectedly while using the _ctypes.so plugin." I use modules with ctype components on a daily basis, and haven't made any major changes to my python installation recently. The actually _ctypes.so file looks normal:

```
$ ls -l _ctypes.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  148720 Nov 12 22:12 _ctypes.so
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in read only filesystems, [in this thread](http://bugs.python.org/issue11048) you can find a patch along with more information.